# Research in Mathematics

Tags: discussion

First year mathematics PhD student here, and I'm wondering what these next few years are going to be like and how to get the most out of my research opportunities and contribute something valuable to the math community. I was wondering where to find information about research as a process and good (preferably empirically-supported) research practices or habits for PhD students in general.

Technically this question is cognitive in nature about how and why researchers do certain practices and which are best for max'ing out productivity. I'm also looking for information about PhD student experiences as a group.

Wasn't sure where or with what tags to post this on here.

Comment: Off-topic – your question isn't about MathOverflow.

Comment: Could you maybe make a suggestion of where I should post this question then?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Since the OP is asking whether some kind of questions is allowed on MO, so I think it is a valid question for meta.MO. (Although to be honest, the description of the question they want to ask is not very clear to me.) And it should be tagged ([meta-tag:allowed-questions]).

Comment: @TannerStrunk A reasonable thing to do is to have a look on other questions to see what is allowed here or on other sites. Here on MO you could have a look at the tags ([tag:career]) and ([tag:advice]). You might look around at [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/), they even [have productivity tag](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity). And maybe you could also have a look at [productivity.SE](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/). I will stress that I am not familiar enough with those sites to judge what is on-topic there, you'll have to see yourself.

Comment: And perhaps I will also add link to this question: [On starting graduate school and common pitfalls…](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27299/on-starting-graduate-school-and-common-pitfalls), since it seems to be at least related to what you're interested in. But notice that the question was asked in 2010. Since the standards of any site evolve, the question by itself cannot be considered as evidence that similar questions are still on-topic on this site.

Comment: I'd suggest, Tanner, that instead of posting your question, you should pose your question to the person in charge of graduate studies in your department.